# git submodule foreach: execute read

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible to execute a read inside a git foreach?

```
git submodule foreach 'read -p "test"; echo $REPLY'
```

does not work at all as the read gets the input from git itself - which is the objname and hash here.
Is there any chance to read interactively of the console?

Answer (score 1):

You can if you redirect input/output to `/dev/tty`. You will want to check whether a tty is available with [`isatty` based methods](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) first when you do this kind of thing.

E.g., create a `./test.sh` like so

```
exec </dev/tty >/dev/tty
read -p "Enter text:" VALUE
echo "got: $VALUE"
```

And then

```
git submodule foreach ../test.sh
```

Will do the right thing, e.g. in my testing

```
sehe@meerkat:~/custom/MONO$ git submodule foreach ../test.sh
Entering 'cecil'
Enter text:a
got: a
Entering 'glib'
Enter text:b
got: b
Entering 'gtk-sharp'
Enter text:c
got: c
...
```