# How to use --reference with multiple submodules

Tags: git

Let's say I have a reference repo with many submodules initialized as follows:

```
git clone "ssh://$USER@example.com/my_repo" repo_reference
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I'm cloning it again using `--reference`:

```
git clone "ssh://$USER@example.com/my_repo" --reference repo_reference repo
```

And now, I want to initialize its submodules using `repo_reference` as a reference.

#### Attempt 1

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --reference repo_reference
```

But the reference flag seems to be ignored. It does full clone from the remote for each submodule.

#### Attempt 2

I hoped I can use the `$sm_path` variable:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --reference 'repo_reference/$sm_path'
```

But it is not resolved:

```
fatal: reference repository 'repo_reference/$sm_path' is not a local repository.
```

#### Attempt 3

I tried using `git submodule foreach --recursive`, so I can initialize submodules one by one. But this command [does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8778323/1282773) unless all submodules are initialized and updated.

#### Question

How do I avoid the full clone and make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are cloning the repository fresh, you can use [`--recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt).

```
git clone \
  "ssh://$USER@example.com/my_repo" \
  --reference repo_reference repo \
  --recurse-submodules
```

I would *assume* that the clone command would pass the reference to the submodule initialisation. Would have to look at the `git` source code to check that assumption though.

Comment: Tested — it works.

Answer (score 1):

After the initial clone run a loop over all submodules from `.gitmodules` and update submodules one by one:

```bash
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' |
while read path_key path; do
    git submodule update --init --reference="repo_reference/$path" "$path"
done
```

Please note double quotes — they're used instead of single quotes (apostrophes) to allow shell to expand the variable `$path`.

I tested this and it works for me.

No recursion, sorry.