# "git submodule foreach" not executed in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

git version 2.37.3

I have a Jenkins pipeline where I'm trying to run Git commands on a Git submodule, like this

```
// Either checkout the passed-in branch, or if the branch doesn't
// exist, checkout master
def checkoutBranch(final String branch) {
  dir(env.WORKSPACE) {
    sh """
      git submodule foreach \'git checkout $branch || git checkout master\'
    """
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the command is not executed, that is, I simply get this on the console

```
Running in /home/jenkins/workspace/Utilities/Playground/test-submodule
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git submodule foreach git checkout feature/test-new-scripts || git checkout master
[Pipeline] }
```

I'm 100% sure that `env.WORKSPACE` has the Git submodule repo. Why is that? TIA.

Comment: It's a classic mistake with Git submodules. See [git submodule foreach not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778323/git-submodule-foreach-not-working)